# Form date not matched when storing to MySQL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created an event page that shows the current date and time for registration. But day and month are changed when I used to store the registration date in the MySQL database.

**event.php**

```
<form name="eventForm" action="event-process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="registraionDate" id="datepicker" value="<?php print date('m-d-Y H:i'); ?>">
</form>
```

Date Shown in form - August, 09
08-09-2021 14:14

**event-process.php**

```
$registraionDate= $_POST['registraionDate'];
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($registraionDate));
```

Output Date - September, 08
2021-09-08 14:14:00

Comment: If you are using custom format to show date in the form you should probably use the same custom format when parsing date on server side

Answer (score 1):

Please see the formats accepted by `strtotime`: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.date.php

You should apply one of them to your date in form, in order to be possible to parse it back using `strtotime`.

Alternatively, if you want to show date in custom format, you can use `date_create_from_format` in your event-process.php, like this:

```
$registraionDate= $_POST['registraionDate'];
print date_create_from_format('m-d-Y H:i', $registraionDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Sorry, seems like working for me: https://3v4l.org/MZPrn. Could you provide error message returned?

Comment: Now it's working cool, sorry I have missed the hour and minute.

Answer (score 0):

You simply inverted the 'm' and the 'd' in the format of your date in the "processus-événement.php" file

Comment: Actually, that's; the requirement to display the date in MONTH, DAY & YEAR